# copying files to raspberry pi from usb flash

Tags: raspbian

while trying to copy files from usb flash memory plugged into the raspberry pi 
to a destination `/var/www/html`

```
the system report error : the copy completed with errors : permission denied
```

How can i copy these files from the usb flash to this destination!?

i tried

```
cd (usb name)
sudo mv (directory file /var/www/html) (usb name )
```

there is an error after second line about permission is denied and failed to preserve ownership for "Directory "

and i notice that this directory is not my files it just empty file created auto after cd command line and then he try to copy it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using cd (your usb drive name)

than do sudo mv (source) (destination)

if this doesnt work, check if your usb drive is read and write, not only read.

Hoped this help you!

Comment: and how i select the destination the file will be transferred to ?
thanks in advance

Comment: The answer above is just expiremental not very sure it will work it should do.

Comment: the destenation is the sudo mv (file) (destination)

Comment: k i will try it but so far you mean cd  (usb name ) then 
sduo mv (file name where will be copied in my example 'httml ) ( destination /var/www/httml)  (usb name ) 

like that ??

Comment: if your usb name is storage then: you would do this:

Comment: cd storage than you would do sudo mv /var/www/httml storage than do ls, you should see your file there.

Comment: there is an errorr
mv : cannot create symbolic link '/media/pi/storage/html/phpmyadmin
mv:failed to preserve ownership for /media/pi/storage/html/index.html operation not premitted

Comment: another thing is the file is not shown in the directory i can see them through the usb falsh but not from the directory

Comment: yes if they are hidden files than you need to open the files application and click file and scroll to show hidden files. for some reason i still encpunter this issue even after i do this. another option is to use the terminal to goto the file with cd and ls.

Comment: how can i copy them with ls ?

Comment: i dont know how to copy but i know how to move files with mv.      cd = see directory.     mv= move.   ls= list.  mk= make directory.  check out this website: https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/usage/terminal/

Comment: @Namo: `cp` stands for **c**o**p**y, see the [man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/cp.1.html) for more info. **||** @Darkest N2O: `cd` stands for **c**hange **d**irectory, please read [it's man-page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/cd.1posix.html) to avoid future problems.